# How Do I Separate an Array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, typescript

I'm creating an application with Angular2, and I have an array of parties.

```
const PARTIES: Party[] = [
  { id: 1, title: "Main Event", description: "The biggest, most extravagant event in the last 10,000,000 years." },
  { id: 2, title: "Secondary Event", description: "The not as biggest, less extravagant event in the last 10,000,000 years." },
  { id: 3, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 4, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 5, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 6, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 7, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 8, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 9, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 10, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" }
];
```

While preserving the original array, I would like to split this array up into segments of 3.

In plain old JavaScript, I would use the following.

```
var chunk_size = 3;
var arr = PARTIES;
var groups = arr.map(function(e,i){
    return i%chunk_size===0 ? arr.slice(i,i+chunk_size) : null;
})
.filter(function(e){ return e; });
PARTIES = groups
```

However, I'm using TypeScript. Is there any possible way to perform what I'm trying to achieve using TypeScript?

Comment: What makes you think you can't do with TypeScript what you could with JavaScript?

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to implement this functionality if it's so easy? @Marty

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was if something was in fact working in JavaScript, it would work perfectly fine in TypeScript as well :-)

Comment: That's understandable, but this code breaks my application @Marty

Comment: What errors do you get? As Basarat said, that original code isn't valid anyway which would break your application if it were plain JS as well.

Comment: Quite an unusual and slightly inefficient use of map and filter combo here. If you would like to remain in array methods you might also try reduce such as `var groups = arr.reduce((p,c,i,a) => i%chunk_size === 0 ? p.concat([a.slice(i,i+chunk_size)]):p,[]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JavaScript code:

```
var chunk_size = 3;
var arr = PARTIES;
var groups = arr.map(function(e,i){
    return i%chunk_size===0 ? arr.slice(i,i+chunk_size) : null;
})
.filter(function(e){ return e; });
PARTIES = groups
```

Is not correct. If it was *it would be valid TypeScript* and it would just work because JavaScript is TypeScript https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html :)

## Fix

The following is a working sample :

```
const PARTIES = [
  { id: 1, title: "Main Event", description: "The biggest, most extravagant event in the last 10,000,000 years." },
  { id: 2, title: "Secondary Event", description: "The not as biggest, less extravagant event in the last 10,000,000 years." },
  { id: 3, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 4, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 5, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 6, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 7, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 8, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 9, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" },
  { id: 10, title: "Another Event", description: "N/A" }
];

var chunk_size = 3;
const groups = PARTIES.map(function(e,i){
    return i%chunk_size===0 ? PARTIES.slice(i,i+chunk_size) : null;
})
.filter(x=>!!x)

console.log(groups);
```

Some notes on the fixes:

- const cannot be reassigned. So you cannot reassign to PARTIES
- the type of PARTIES (`[]`) is not the same as the types of `groups` (`[][]`) so you don't want to assign that anyways
- Better to use true `boolean` in `filter` instead of truthy / falsy checks. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/truthy.html

Comment: I'm doing it within a class, would that effect it?

Comment: Thanks, man. I was trying to do it from within a class. @basarat